# Country specific language support

Tags: translation, customlabel, label

**Situation**

For a community we want to support up to 5 languages per country. Each language has to be different. E.g.

- For Germany we support German and English (Germany)
- For Switzerland: German (Swiss), English (Swiss), French (Swiss), Romansh(Swiss)
- Denmark: Danish (DK) and English (DK)
- USA: English (US)

**Issue**

The general issue is that we are not able to use the same language twice. One of our issues is that the legislation differs by country. E.g.

The legal drinking age in the US is 21 but in Switzerland 18. Therefore the salesforce label named "LegalDringingAge" is translated in English (Swiss) with "18 years" but in English (US) with "21 years".

I.a.w. English can be translated different by country.

As I learned from the documentation 3 type of languages are supported:

1. Fully supported languages
2. End-user languages
3. Platform-only languages

**Question**

- Is it possible to add languages like English (Switzerland) or English (Germany)?
- Is there a better way to handle country specific labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add more languages.

You could add conditions in your pages to render certain parts of the content based on variables likes the language selected and the domain for example.

If you want to get more sophisticated you could have a variable object in which you could do a variable substitution on the content of the page based on multiple conditions such as the language selected and the current country/domain.